# Keep textarea from changing size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using jQuery to alter the font size and line height of text in a textarea, but when these values are changed, the textarea gets really tall (if changing the line height to be bigger) or really tiny (shrinking the entire thing, if making the font size smaller.)

I would hopefully like to fix this problem without getting rid of the draggable resize feature that is built into the textarea, but if that's not possible then that's fine. It's more important to me that these other problems are fixed.

Here is my javascript (jQuery) code:

```
  $("#text").css("line-height", lineSpace);

  $("#text").css("letter-spacing", letterSpace+"px");

  $("#text").css("font-size", textSize+"px");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried CSS?  
`textarea {
    resize: none;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var lineSpace = 2;
  var letterSpace = 5;
  var textSize = 20;
  $(".fixedTextarea").css("line-height", lineSpace);
  $(".fixedTextarea").css("letter-spacing", letterSpace+"px");
  $(".fixedTextarea").css("font-size", textSize+"px");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea style="overflow:auto;resize:none;width:200px;height:200px;" class="fixedTextarea" col="10" rows="5">
 I'm using jQuery to alter the font size and line height of text in a textarea, but when these values are changed
</textarea>
```

Fixed your TextArea with width & height.

Answer (score 1):

```
<b><textarea style="resize:none"  name="name" cols="num" rows="num"></textarea></b>
```